# Kentico Nested Macro Comparison

Tags: macros, kentico

I want to compare a url to a specific path to see if they match. I have tried so many variations and just can't get it to work, the two items I need to use are

```
{%CurrentDocument.RelativeURL.Replace("~","")%}
```

and

```
{&/{0}/{1}/{2}|(tolower)&}
```

In the current test scenario, both of these return the same string, however, when I put them together

```
{%CurrentDocument.RelativeURL.Replace("~","")|(equals){&/{0}/{1}/{2}|(tolower)&}|(truevalue)yes#%}
```

I get a false result displaying, I'm pretty positive it's because I can't nest a path expression inside an expression but not sure if there is another way? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?types_of_macros.htm) you should be able to substitute path macro with `{%Path.path%}`. Then there is no need to nest different types of macros but use the Path the same way as CurrentDocument.